# Helping understanding bashing scripting in run-command

Tags: bash, azure, variables, azure-cli

I have inherited some code I am trying to understand.  it is the combination of azure cli commands and linux bash scripts

```
#!/bin/bash -e

info "Installing Dependencies"

declare -a PIDS=()

# "Deploying into the VMs"
for i in $(seq 1 $NODES_NUM); do
    THIS_VM_NAME="${VM_NAME}${i}"

    # "Check if the VM exists"
    if `az vm list -o table | grep -q "${THIS_VM_NAME}"`; then
        info "Deploying: Installing deps and Pairty, Executing for ${THIS_VM_NAME}"

        PIDS[${i}]=$!

        az vm run-command invoke --name ${THIS_VM_NAME} \
            --command-id RunShellScript \
            --resource-group ${RSC_GRP_NAME} \
            --query "output[].message | join('\n\n', @)" \
            --scripts @${TEMPLATES}/user-data.sh &

        PIDS[${i}]=$!
    fi
done

# wait for all pids
info "Waiting for Completion.."
for pid in ${PIDS[*]}; do
    wait $pid
done
```

I would like appreciate pointer understanding how

```
@${TEMPLATES}/user-data.sh &

        PIDS[${i}]=$!
```

works.

- I cannot see the variable been imported into the scripts
- The file is located in another folders, and it micraculously works?
- I would also appreciate pointers on the `PIDS` does it mean that processes can run concurrently?

Comment: The `az` commands are being run in background (the `&`) so they happen concurrently. The first `PIDS[${i}]=$!` seems pointless, since the second will just overwrite it. After the first loop kicks off all the jobs in background, the second loop waits for each to finish.  `${TEMPLATES}` is likely exported in the calling environment.

Comment: `if \`az vm list -o table | grep -q "${THIS_VM_NAME}"\` ` will never be true - take out the backticks.

Comment: The `@` before `${TEMPLATES}` is just a literal unquoted string, exactly like `/user-data.sh` after it.

Comment: @PaulHodges thanks for your response. Re: ${TEMPLATES} I cant seem to find it anywhere in the repo. Is it posible that it forms a relative reference as there is a `templates/user-data.sh` folder above?

Comment: As there are other bugs which clearly prevent this from running successfully, perhaps the programmer simply forgot to ever set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the test, the same thing happens to me. But two weeks ago it works well. I will show you something:

**Last**

[image]
[image]

The command and the output are OK. And in the backend, the script should be like above.

**Now**

[image]
[image]

You can see that the command does not set the parameters in the backend. But if you just run the shell command with parameters it also works well.

[image]
[image]

According to the test, maybe there something not good happens to the CLI there days. You can wait for serial days and then run the CLI command again.

> The file is located in another folders, and it micraculously works?

If you mean the shell script in another folder, it will also work well if the CLI command works as usual.

> I would also appreciate pointers on the PIDS does it mean that
>   processes can run concurrently?

There is something you should pay attention to. The CLI command runs as a process in the Linux, so it can run multi in the backend at the same time. But the `run-command` just runs the shell script through the agent with the VM and it just runs one script at one time. You can get the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions).

In addition, you can use the VM extension to do what you want to do through Run Command and it's more available.

Hope this will help you.